# Display Author Name (outside of loop)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an area of my index.php file that I'm customizing in a theme whereby I would like to display the most recent post and some additional meta. I was able to pull the featured image, post title (and link), & the date; but not the author. I've tried various examples from the WP boards with no luck. The latest attempt below:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1');
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        //$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
            $post_author = get_user_by( 'id', $recent->post_author );
            echo '<div class="full-width" id="featured-post" style="background-image: url('. $feat_image .')">';

            echo '<div class="row featured-post-meta"><div class="small-8 columns">';
            echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Read: '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a></h2>';
            echo '<p>'. $post_author->display_name .' | '. get_the_time('F jS, Y') .'</p>';
            echo '<a class="read-post" href="'. get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'">Read the post</a>';
            echo '</div></div></div>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You mean outside of `foreach loop` ?

Comment: No, he mans outside the Wordpress post loop. There was a similar question asked over at [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65548/how-to-get-author-id-outside-the-loop).  I know the QA is specific for the author ID, but there are some clues for the author name as well.

Comment: Please provide the code where actual loop is running

Comment: Apologies, yes; this is in a foreach loop outside of the main WP loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your foreach loop:

```
$post_author = get_user_by( 'id', $recent['post_author'] );
```

This gets you the user object which looks like what you were trying to do with $curauth.

You could then output $post_author->display_name in place of $curauth.

```
echo '<p>'. $post_author->display_name .' ...
```

Comment: didn't display the name still. WP or PHP are not my native tongue :)

Comment: OK can you post the code you used including my revision so I can check?

Comment: OK beneath $post_author please add echo '<pre>'; print_r( $post_author ); echo '</pre>'; and then post the output in the original question.

Comment: There was nothing output

Comment: The function you're using returns an associative array but my answer applied to an object. Please use the updated version.